# Почему не работает эмулятор в android studio

Tags: windows, android-studio, виртуальная-машина

Не работает эмулятор я уже все что можно было перепробовал процессор amd ryzen 7 3700x . виртуализация включена! пробовал каждую галочки снимать перезапускать и тд все перепробовал, в биосе виртуализацию тоже включил, в диспетчере задач тоже отображается что виртуализация включена . в самой андроид студио тоже все что можно включил . в avd manager выбираю устройство нажимаю запустить что-то подгружается, появиться  справа окно что ошибки не обнаружены и ничего не происходи. целостность винды тоже проверил, все в порядке. в самом эмулятор может какая-то ошибка появиться но не понимаю что это значит . проще говоря нажимаю запуск эмулятора что-то подгружается и все тишина, никакой реакции, ни ошибки,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ничего ..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте скриншоты только при необходимости - логи и код следует вставлять текстом.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте создать новый AVD, возможно со старым перестал работать, такое бывает